# Incorrect Rows.Count in an interrupted range (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, rows, vba

I'm trying to get the Rows.Count of a range which consists of two combined ranges:

`Set rng = Union(Range1,Range2)`

Unfortunately the rng.Rows.Count returns the Rows.Count of Range1, and I would expect it to return Rows.Count of Range1+Range2.

The actual range I tested it with is this: `$A$27:$G$41,$A$43:$G$43`

Its Rows.Count property returns 15 but in this range there are 16 rows.

Any ideas how to get the correct Rows.Count without much juggling?

Comment: The two solutions below will work, provided that your ranges do not have any overlap.

Comment: @sam092: Yeah, that's a concern. However, if there are overlaps, a comparison of `Rows.Count` of each area and returning the highest value *might* suffice. ;)

Comment: @BK201 not necessarily. Try `Range("A1:C8")` and `Range("A2:B9")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim arr as range
Dim rws as long

For each arr in rng.areas
    Rws = rws + arr.rows.count
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Res = 0
    Set rng1 = Range("A27:G41")
    Set rng2 = Range("A43:G43")
    Set rng = Union(rng1, rng2)
    For Each area In rng.Areas
        Res = Res + area.Rows.Count
        Debug.Print Res
    Next area
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.